# How to identify Javascript version

Tags: javascript, version

We used javascript in a code and did not specify the version. It is working on IE11 but not IE8. Is there a way to figure out what earliest version it is compatible with, i.e. is there any tool where you can put the URL and it tells you that which earliest version of browser will be able to support your code (based on what script is used in the code) without actually trying it in various versions of browsers?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic here. However, you may find better luck [SoftwareRecs.SE](//softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour). Remember to read [their question requirements](//softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they are more strict than this site.

Comment: Do a web search for *"javascript feature detection"*. Also there are polyfills for  many modern methods to be used when they don't exist

Comment: You may be better off loading a polyfill for IE8 browsers. You can load it conditionally using IE's legacy "conditional comments" feature, so the other browsers don't need to download it.

Answer (score 2):

No, or at least not that I'm aware of (other than manually trying it in the different browser versions yourself, or using a tool like `Browserstack` to preview it in them).

That said, it's also a really bad idea to include a fixed version number. The better approach is to use a practice known as [graceful degradation](https://www.google.com/search?q=graceful+degradation&oq=graceful+degradation&aqs=chrome..69i57.3351j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), which basically means to fail in a way that will still leave your site usable.

You can also use [polyfills](https://www.google.com/search?q=polyfills&oq=polyfills&aqs=chrome..69i57.2231j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) to fill in more modern functions that may be missing on older browsers.

Finally, it is common that you won't officially support all the way back in time. For example, where I work, we only support back to IE11 and fairly recent versions of Chrome. This doesn't mean it might not work in those older versions, we just don't officially support it. Basing support on "what works now" isn't a good approach, because you might use something in the future that would shrink your support.

Instead, pick a line in the sand and then test for all of those.